# Theme Customization via Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've just recently dived into Themes editing via Child Themes (I know. So last summer right but butter late than never). Since I'm a "programmer" by trial & error, I'm not sure what I'm doing most of the time.

Can anyone gimme any clue how to edit this kinda setup via Child Themes

1st layer: get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );

2nd layer: do_action( 'hestia_blog_post_template_part', 'default' );

3rd layer: class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php [where the real thing really resides]

Thanks guys

Comment: are using the free theme Hestia ? if it's that, you can customise the hook `hestia_blog_post_template_part` if you need to change something on all template that use the class Hestia_Blog_Post_Layout. or you can create a new file template-parts/content.php

Comment: I read about Hooks and I tried to change it. But unfortunately it didn’t go well

Comment: if you just want to change the archive, create a file `template-parts/content.php` in the child theme. I just test it and that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override a template by taking the template file from the main theme, and then putting it in the same location in the child theme. So lets say the template is called `class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php` from `mainthemefolder/templates/class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php` then copy it to `childthemefolder/templates/class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php`.

**Update**

It looks like your theme (Hestia) isn't using the default way to use templates. Its definitely not you doing something wrong about how a child theme is supposed to work. I added template-parts/content.php to the child, and changed

`hestia_blog_post_template_part`

to

`hestia_blog_post_template_part2`

, and in the `class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php` in the child-theme I changed this line

`add_action( 'hestia_blog_post_template_part', array( $this, 'render' ), 2 );`

to this

`add_action( 'hestia_blog_post_template_part2', array( $this, 'render' ), 2 );`

But then it still didn't work. Then I noticed that the Class in `class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php` is loaded in `hestia/inc/core/class-hestia-autoloader`, in which i changed

`'Hestia_Blog_Post_Layout'                     => HESTIA_PHP_INCLUDE . 'views/blog',`

to

`'Hestia_Blog_Post_Layout2'                     => HESTIA_PHP_INCLUDE . '../../hestia-child/inc/views/blog',`

But it is still not working ...

For now I give up, sorry.

Comment: Tried this @Snuwerd unfortunately it didnt do anything

Comment: I just installed Hestia to test. Which place are you using to test if you are editing the right location? Currently I made a blog post and viewed it, is this where you are trying to change it, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. I want to change the view for archive.php

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. I tried to do the same thing you did too but didn't find the last bit. It's unfortunate that I can't use the Child Theme properly for Hestia. I really want to use the original markup for displaying the content, just want to change some parts of it. I may as well go with @Kaperto suggestion eventually but still sad I can't depend on the original codes

Comment: I found this link. Will it help? https://docs.themeisle.com/article/918-how-to-override-sections-in-hestia-pro

Comment: It depends on if there is a hook for the part you want to change. Not all parts you want to change may have a hook, looking at the code of `class-hestia-blog-post-layout.php`. Hooks start with `do_action(` or `apply_filters(`.

Comment: Hi @Snuwerd I did my first change :) But it is appearing above the post title. Any idea what should I do? This is my code https://justpaste.it/78gv2

Comment: Yessss I did it @Snuwerd. I used `return ` instead of `echo`